# CAN module python 3

Tags: python, can-bus

I have recently purchased a [PICAN](http://skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/1220) 2 board that uses the CAN module,

```
import CAN
bus = CAN.interface.Bus(channel='can0', bustype='socketcan_native')
msg = CAN.Message(arbitration_id=0x13C, data=[0,25,1,3,1,4,1]
bus.send(msg)
```

my error: AtributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interface'

Comment: The module is called 'can' and not 'CAN'. That's what probably is causing the issue.

Comment: that's what I thought too, if I go lower case it says that the module doesn't even exist

Comment: Which python version are you running it in?

Comment: I am using Python 3

Comment: Can you import CAN and can and print CAN.__file__ and can.__file__ and post the result

Comment: I found that the file name was CAN, and that there is no can module installed, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rfkortekaas said - the module is called `can`. I suspect you have called one of your python files `CAN.py` which is why you get the error you're seeing.

Have you downloaded and installed the [python-can](https://bitbucket.org/hardbyte/python-can) package?

Have a look at the [python-can socketcan documentation](http://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/latest/socketcan.html#socketcan-quickstart) - that is what the PICAN2 board uses.